# Bootstrap 4 and breakpoints

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am tying to create a UI in photoshop that will be used to render a full-width site.  I have never used flexbox before and I've never created a full-width site before using it.

I'm wondering if I simply stick to the default bootstrap breakpoints or if I need to be doing something entirely different.

An example of the type of full-width layout:
[image: full-width sample]

Answer (score 1):

Thou this is a very general question, I'd have following advice for you:

I would use both, grid & flexbox, since, grids are great for building the bigger picture and make it really easy to manage the overall layout of the page. They are also able to handle more unorthodox and asymmetrical designs.

Flexbox is great at aligning the content inside elements so you can use flexboxes to position the smaller details of a design.

You could use CSS grids for 2D layouts (rows AND columns) and Flexbox for one dimension only (rows OR columns).

There is no reason to use only CSS grids or only flexbox - they work well together in their respective field of usage.

For layouting and screencasts I can definitly recommend [Adobe XD](https://www.adobe.com/at/products/xd.html?gclid=CjwKCAjworfdBRA7EiwAKX9HeDPHs3kjMtR1U4-yB5tvfzVmLSA2EAqjcM6v7mVndZ0UipurEgy1UxoClLgQAvD_BwE&sdid=88X75SKW&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!274586771984!e!!g!!adobe%20xd&ef_id=WsiHUgAAAF7sqDsD:20180928073600:s) - quite fresh in the Adobe-family and free for now.

I hope that gave you some idea how to approach your project andf plan the layout according to your needs.

**EDIT:**

Have a look at [this article](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) - it should give you a fair understanding on how to set breakpoints according to your layout and the media/device.

Comment: I'm actually looking for specific instructions on breakpoints.  I'm only doing the graphic design and the client says he will get someone to handle the slicing and rendering to html.

The issue however is that I don't know what breakpoints to deliver to client and neither does the client.  He simply knows thet will be using bootstrap 4 and that he wants the design to be full-width.

Comment: look at my edit  - If you are looking for specific instructions on a project where both sides are unsure on the breakpoints I'd suggest you sit down with your customer/client and talk about the layout? It's hard to give you any advice when you don't supply the layout..

Comment: That bootstrap article is actually what I was looking at before coming here. It's hard to provide a layout when I'm just in the planning stages with the client.  He knows he will be using bootstrap and he know he wants the design to be full-width.

I've edited my original post to add in a sample of the full-width layout style the client is after.

Comment: Don't get me wrong buddy, but I'm not gonna do the work for you. You have all the necessary information (assuming you read and understood the article on breakpoints) as well as the approximate layout - where is the problem realizing what you are trying to achieve? If you don't understand front-end layouting and webdesign I strongly suggest you visit a higher-education-facilty and get your skills or leave this to people that have the skills and are knowledgeable about what they are doing.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond but I'm pretty sure I'm not asking you to "do the work for me" :)

I'm merely asking for advice on where to start - everyone has to start somewhere.  I'll keep researching, thanks for taking the time to respond though.

Comment: start with identifying your major elements  (i.e. sidenav, header, footer, your main content-area and their according subelements) and then definine how and where they should break according to the given screen-res..